# MUI Grid Component Causing Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Title.

```
function Times() {
    const styles = {
        heroContainer: {
          height: 700,
          backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          backgroundPosition: 'center',
          width: '100vw'
        }
       };

  return (
      <Box>
          <Grid container xs={12} columns={2} style={styles.heroContainer}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={3} style={{padding: 200}}>
                <h1>Service Times</h1>
                <h2>8:45 &amp; 10:30</h2>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
      </Box> 



  )
}
```

I have tried wrapping the grid in a container rather than a box and setting the maxWidth to 100% but nothing seems to be helping.

Comment: I think your issue is to do with your hero container height. You shouldnt be styling the Grid like that in MUI but rather style the box

Answer (score 1):

### The root of problem

Probably one of your upper elements (most likely `body`) have some `margin`.
And setting `width: 100vh` will result in your Grid being more wide than its container. Thus horizontal scrolling.

### Solution

So you either need to remove `width: '100vw'` from your Grid styles, or to find that margin and set that to 0.
I recommend the former option, because the Grid component has the `width: 100%` by default.

### Other problems

Also there are several other problems with your code. You can't use both `container` and  `xs` attributes in the same `Grid`. And the `columns` attributes is not the count of columns, but the total number of fractions you need to divide between your children grids.
So your correct code would be like this:

```
function Times() {
  const styles = {
    heroContainer: {
      height: 700,
      backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      backgroundPosition: "center",
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Grid container style={styles.heroContainer}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={3} style={{ padding: 200 }}>
          <h1>Service Times</h1>
          <h2>8:45 &amp; 10:30</h2>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

See [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/) for better understanding of this component.